# ReduxForm works only one way

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

I have two `Field`s in my `ReduxForm`: one is a `select` field, another one is `radio button group`. When I update any of them the state changes correctly which I see using `redux-dev-tools`. When I change the `select` field, the `radio button group` changes accordingly, however, it is not working the other way round. What could be the possible cause for that and how to fix it?

Possibly irrelevant (still might be useful to look):

The state looks like that:

`fscoreFilter: {fscore: ['fscore_2', 0.5], qscore: ['qscore_1', 2.5]}`

`fscore` and `qscore` are two `radio button groups` with their respective `select` fields. Initial value looks like that:

`fscoreFilter: {fscore: ['fscore_0', null], qscore: ['qscore_0', null]}`

I need it this way because there is also a text field for each of the `radio button group` that allows entering custom values. `Radio button group` allows entering some common discrete ones.

To update the state I am using `onChange` method, forming on the fly from the value passed to it the necessary state. So, for instance `Select` `onChange` is getting just a number which I take and transform into `qscore: ['qscore_1', 2.5]`, unite with the other unchanged `fscore` and pass it to the `onChange` passed to the component which is ultimately `onChange` of the `Field`.

Comment: Please post code examples. Seeing your state, your state selectors, and how your components are accessing the state will all probably be necessary to get to the correct answer.

Comment: I doubt I can add anything more. I initially did not include the remaining explanation after the first paragraph of the question because there things are exceedingly complex and are in essence irrelevant. I see the behavior presented in the first paragraph and just need to know what could possibly cause it. There is a hierarchy of 10 different components in between the final `Field` and the abstraction that I am forced to use.

Comment: i thing you need to use the `reduxForm()` decorator of `redux-form` on your form export and not update the state using the `onChange` method.

Comment: The decorator `reduxForm` is present. Just looked it up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not supply `value` to the top `Select` component. So, the `onChange` `Select` (actually `Dropdown` input type) was updating `state` when it was interacted with and the `radio button group` was updating because it has set names (but `Select` was not having) but when `Select` was rerendered due to `radio button group` change the `value` inside of it was not modified and set accordingly.